# Jquery - After changing div size (expanding and collapsing), scrollbar disappears

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a layout with one div that on click of a button expands to the size of the screen. Before expanding the div has enough content to force it to scroll. After collapsing back to the original size, the scroll bar disappears and some content is hidden.

What could be causing that? I tried setting the overflow auto css again in the toggle function, but it doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">

<title>Untitled 2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var height = $( window ).height();
    var width = $( window ).width();
    canvasHeight = height - 282;
    $("#mainCanvas").css({"height" : canvasHeight});
    $("#header").css({"min-width" : width});
    $("#mainCanvas").css({"min-width" : width});
    $("#legend").css({"min-width" : width});
    $("#footer").css({"min-width" : width});

    $("#toggle").click(function() {
            if($("#mainCanvas").height() != height) {
                $("#header").hide();
                $("#legend").hide();
                $("#footer").hide();
                $("#detail").animate({"top" : '0px'});
                $("#toggle").animate({"top" : '0px'});
                $("#mainCanvas").animate({"height": height}, {"queue": false, "duration": 500}).animate({"width": width}, 500);
                $("#toggle").html('<img id="expand" src="img/collapse.png">');
            }
            else {
                $("#mainCanvas").animate({"height": canvasHeight}, {"queue": false, "duration": 500}).animate({"width": '100%'}, 800); 
                $("#header").show();
                $("#legend").show();
                $("#footer").show();
                $("#detail").animate({"top" : '92px'});
                $("#toggle").animate({"top" : '92px'});
                $("#toggle").html('<img id="expand" src="img/expand.png">');
            }
        }); // End Expand/Collapse

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
img#expand {
    width: 20px;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

/* Application Details */
div#toggle {
    left: 95%; 
    top: 92px; 
    width: 34px;
    height: 29px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: white;
    padding-top: 5px; 
    position: fixed;
}

</style>
</head>

<body> 

<div id="header" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 92px; background: fuchsia;"></div>
<div id="mainCanvas" style="float: left; width: 100%; background: blue; overflow: auto;">
    <div id="toggle"><img id="expand" alt="" src="img/expand.png"></div>
    <div id="content" style="width: 100%"><p>Paragraph ParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraphParagraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p><p>Paragraph</p></div>
</div>
<div id="legend" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 140px; background: lime;"></div>
<div id="footer" style="float: left; width: 100%; height: 50px; background: gray;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can you provide jsFiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, jquery is turning *overflow* css property of the #mainCanvas to *hidden*.
A quick hack to fix it is set it back to "auto" in animates's *complete* argument:

```
    $("#toggle").click(function() {
            if($("#mainCanvas").height() != height) {
                $("#header").hide();
                $("#legend").hide();
                $("#footer").hide();
                $("#detail").animate({"top" : '0px'});
                $("#toggle").animate({"top" : '0px'});
                $("#mainCanvas").animate({"height": height}, {"queue": false, "duration": 500}).animate({"width": width}, 500,function() {
$(this).css("overflow","auto")
});
                $("#toggle").html('<img id="expand" src="img/collapse.png">');
            }
            else {
                $("#mainCanvas").animate({"height": canvasHeight}, {"queue": false, "duration": 500}).animate({"width": '100%'}, 800,function() {
$(this).css("overflow","auto")
}); 
                $("#header").show();
                $("#legend").show();
                $("#footer").show();
                $("#detail").animate({"top" : '92px'});
                $("#toggle").animate({"top" : '92px'});
                $("#toggle").html('<img id="expand" src="img/expand.png">');
            }
        }); // End Expand/Collapse
```

(works in IE 8.0)

Answer (score 1):

just the modified **else** part

```
else {
        $("#mainCanvas").css('overflow','auto', 'important');
        $("#mainCanvas").animate({"height": canvasHeight}, {"queue": false, "duration": 500}); 
        $("#header").show();
        $("#legend").show();
        $("#footer").show();
        $("#detail").animate({"top" : '92px'});
        $("#toggle").animate({"top" : '92px'});
        $("#toggle").html('<img id="expand" src="img/expand.png">');      
}
```

[JS FIddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/wNd44/11/)

Comment: p/s: OP should also try to use chaining... instead of declaring a new object for each element of interest. For example, you can use `$('#header, #legend, #footer').show();` and `$('#detail, #toggle').animate(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into your if statement:

```
         $("#content p").css({"overflow" : 'scroll'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hslincoln/wNd44/1/

Comment: Thanks for putting it on jsfiddle so I can see the changes. For me, on clicking the button to expand, it breaks up each paragraph and puts scrollbars around them and then can't collapse.. Not sure if it's my browser, but anyway thanks, my problem has been resovled.

Comment: Not a problem, was good to work through. This works well and is just one more line of code.